# kill - no process found

Tags: linux, unix, process, kill, ps

when I list my processes I have:

> root@adam-ThinkPad-T410:~# ps -e | grep signals
>   11641 pts/0    00:00:00 signals
>   11642 pts/0    00:00:00 signals
>   11643 pts/0    00:00:00 signals

but when I want to kill I get info that there is no such process:

> root@adam-ThinkPad-T410:~# killall -9 11641
>   11641: no process found

I'm quite new to linux and a little bit confused
I tried also "kill 11641" - but still no luck

Comment: `kill 11641` gives exactly the same error? (I doubt that.) Or do you mean, the process is still alive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`killall` expects a process name, e.g. `killall signals` which kills all such processes. Otherwise you should use the process id (which you extraced correctly from `ps`): `kill -9 <PID>` where `-9` is `SIGKILL` and is rather rude, normally a `kill <PID>` is enough (but that sems not to work in your case). `man killall` and `man kill` are your friends.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: Sorry ;)

Comment: LOL.  Not at all.  I see you're a relatively new member and can probably use the additional rep points more than me anyway.  (The one upvote you got already was mine.)  Keep up the good work.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: I guessed your upvote already ;) -- and thanks a lot for your encouraging words.

Answer (score 6):

The grep command returns itself as a process when you pipe it from another command. I suppose that the `process 11641` is the grep process, which essentially has exited (and cannot be killed the way you are trying to terminate it).

Try to do this:

```
ps -e | grep signals | grep -v grep
```

That essentially removes the grep process from the result.

Comment: no, I still have the same id's

Comment: ps -e | grep [s]ignals saves you the grep -v .. I got it from another post here which I unfortunately do not remember and thus can't credit on

Comment: Today I learned that this search matches the grep process itself, and this solved my problem.